# Changing Every Instance of a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

I am trying to WRITE A FUNCTION to change the every instance in a list of
tuples. Basically i need to convert the every instance of the list from ('value', number, 'value') to Arc('value', number, 'value')

```
Input:   [('root', 1, 'a'), ('b', 0.0, 'root'), ('b', 2, 'c'), ('a', 5, 'd'), ('b', 7, 'a')]

def Convert(t):
    t1=('head', 'weight', 'tail')
    t2=namedtuple('Arc', (t1))
    return t2

Required Output: [Arc('root', 1, 'a'), Arc('b', 0.0, 'root'), Arc('b', 2, 'c'), Arc('a', 5, 'd'), Arc('b', 7, 'a')]
```

Comment: Your `Convert` function is literally 4 characters away from doing exactly what you need with a single entry. Please explain where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: i need to change the elements of the tuple list [('root', 1, 'a'), ('b', 0.0, 'root'), ('b', 2, 'c'), ('a', 5, 'd'), ('b', 7, 'a')] as required output and i need my function to work for any provide input of the given form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension to convert your list of tuples to list of named-tuples:

```
t = [ ('root', 1, 'a'), ('b', 0.0, 'root'), ('b', 2, 'c'), ('a', 5, 'd'), ('b', 7, 'a') ]

from collections import namedtuple

Arc = namedtuple('Arc', 'head weight tail')

def Convert(t):
    return [Arc(*item) for item in t]

print(Convert(t))
```

Prints:

```
[Arc(head='root', weight=1, tail='a'), Arc(head='b', weight=0.0, tail='root'), Arc(head='b', weight=2, tail='c'), Arc(head='a', weight=5, tail='d'), Arc(head='b', weight=7, tail='a')]
```